# How to implement gravity and collision in XNA (3d)

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I have been wondering how to implement gravity and collision in C# XNA. I have been trying to get all of this to work, but can't get it working. Now to explain what I have done up till now:

I have imported two 3d models; namely a ball and a cube. I have put the ball inside the cube and want to implement gravity to the ball and have collision on it. So that it bounces around inside the cube. To draw the cube and ball, I have mode a drawModel method:

```
private void DrawModel(Model model, Vector3 position)
    {
        Matrix[] transform = new Matrix[model.Bones.Count];
        float aspectRatio = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;
        model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transform);
        Matrix projection =
            Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f),
            aspectRatio, 1.0f, 10000.0f);
        Matrix view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 800.0f),
            Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                effect.View = view;
                effect.Projection = projection;
                effect.World = transform[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                    Matrix.CreateTranslation(position) *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians(yaw)) *
                    Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.ToRadians(pitch));
            }
            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
```

for position I use Vector3.Zero.

For gravity I have this:

```
modelVelocity += (gravity * elapsed) / friction;
ballPosition += modelVelocity * elapsed;
```

Where the velocity is a random number when the program runs and gravity is Vector3.Down
friction is a constant. Which sort of works, but not really how I want it + I do not understand it 100%. I have gotten this far with some tutorials and forums.

```
protected void Bounce()
    {
        if (ballPosition.X >= boxWidth || ballPosition.X <= -boxWidth)
            modelVelocity.X *= -1;
        if (ballPosition.Y >= boxHeight || ballPosition.Y <= -boxHeight)
            modelVelocity.Y *= -1;
        if (ballPosition.Z >= boxLength || ballPosition.Z <= -boxLength)
            modelVelocity.Z *= -1;
```

The collision is very 'cheap', since it is not really collision. This is how I keep it inside the box

The gravity works kind of how I want it. But when it doesn't bounce anymore, it glitches through the box and keeps going down. Plus I would kind of like to 'throw' it by pressing space bar.

My main question is how to do the collision inside the box without using my method and how to do the gravity correctly. But if anyone has other tips about 3d in XNA. I would really appreciate it, because I am very new to this.

Comment: You shown your drawing code, but can you show your collision/gravity code and point out what did not work with it?

Comment: You can use a method called per pixel collision. It checks collision based on colors. Transparency of a photo will not cause it to collide.

Comment: As far as realistic physics goes, the only thing you have wrong is dividing by friction. If it looks and acts how you want though, "realistic physics" doesn't really matter. Could you narrow the question to something in your code that isn't working like you want?